# How to place anchors on specific coordinates while loading the app and not spawning them ontouch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

im currently developing a solution to for ARCore(Android) with Unity.

My actual problem is that i cant figure out how to give a fixed coordinate to an object to spawn, i dont want to spawn objects while touching the screen, i want them to be there when the app loads, For example:

I want an underground wiresystem to show up in the application on a specific real world zone, so the workers could know where to dig instead of looking at random positions.

I'vve been reading about Anchors, but i have only found examples on using the trackable parameter according to RayCast, like spawning on real time while touching the screen, and not preloading those objects in the app. IS there a way to give real GPS parameters to anchors?